# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 44

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a simple php validation code for a project I'm doing and I'm having it validate first name, last name, and email. I got this error and ive looked over it for atleast 45 mins and can't figure out what it is.

```
<?php
 $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = "";
 $firstname = $lastname = $email = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
 $fnameErr = "First name is required";
}
```

This is line 38-46

Comment: check the code carefully, in this error says your code has a unwanted { symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of the braces haven't been closed.

```
<?php
    $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = "";
    $firstname = $lastname = $email = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
            $fnameErr = "First name is required";
        }
    } // Add an ending brace
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed end your second if condition.
code should be like this.

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
        $fnameErr = "First name is required";
     }
 }//this } symbol you have missed.
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed your second condition bracket and you can update your code which will more readable

```
<?php
 // this is error variable
 $fnameErr = "";
 $lnameErr = "";
 $emailErr = "";

// this is post initial variable define
 $firstname = "";
 $lastname = "";
 $email = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $fnameErr = "First name is required";
  }
}
?>
```

for more information

[PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0):

Use IDE to help you with syntax errors. I think you are in a learning stage, so I would suggest you to use an IDE (Eclipse or Netbeans)

**Missing braces:**

```
 $fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = "";
 $firstname = $lastname = $email = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
 $fnameErr = "First name is required";
}
}//Here
```